# How to QUERY (SQL) in QGIS DB Manager?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

This is my first time using DB Manager to store data.
The Import/Export them was easy.
My point is, when i try to run a QUERY it returns this error!

I´m using QGIS 2.18 , PostgreSQL 9.4

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're using capital letters in names of tables or columns you need to place it in " ". Postgres is case sensitive

Comment: :) If it helped mark answer as correct and/or upvote :)